# My functions sometimes sums wrong a number

Tags: javascript, function

This function takes an array of names and returns the sum of the consonants value defined in a constant. It works perfectly with some arrays, but for some reason it doesn't sum another arrays.

For example:

```
consonantsValue(["maria", "florencia", "vazquez"]); 
//expected output = [13, 26, 28]
//real output = [13, 26, 12]

consonantsValue(["monica", "cecilia", "sepulveda", "gutierrez"]);
//expected output = [12, 9, 19, 35]
//real output = [12, 9, 19, 27]
```

And these are some examples where the functions stops working properly.

Here's my function:

```
function consonantsValue(arr){
            const weight = {
                j: 1,
                s: 1,
                b: 2,
                k: 2,
                t: 2,
                c: 3,
                l: 3,
                d: 4,
                m: 4,
                v: 4,
                n: 5,
                ñ: 5, 
                w: 5,
                f: 6,
                x: 6,
                g: 7, 
                p: 7,
                y: 7,
                h: 8,
                q: 8, 
                Z: 8,
                r: 9
              }      
              const names = arr;
              
              const resultConsonants = names.map(name => {
                return name.split('').reduce((sum, char) => {
                  if(weight[char] != null) {
                    sum += weight[char];
                  }  
                  return sum;
                }, 0);
              });
              
              return resultConsonants;
            }
```

Comment: Why do you expect 28 or 35? Can you show where the math comes from? Looks like a typo question, you forgot a key of `z` (lower case)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your 'Z' is in uppercase, so better double check for both lower and uppercase in weight

```js
function consonantsValue(arr) {
  const weight = {
    j: 1,
    s: 1,
    b: 2,
    k: 2,
    t: 2,
    c: 3,
    l: 3,
    d: 4,
    m: 4,
    v: 4,
    n: 5,
    ñ: 5,
    w: 5,
    f: 6,
    x: 6,
    g: 7,
    p: 7,
    y: 7,
    h: 8,
    q: 8,
    Z: 8,
    r: 9,
  }
  const names = arr

  const resultConsonants = names.map((name) => {
    return name.split("").reduce((sum, char) => {
      if (
        weight[char.toLowerCase()] != null ||
        weight[char.toUpperCase()] != null
      ) {
        sum += weight[char.toLowerCase()] || weight[char.toUpperCase()]
      }
      return sum
    }, 0)
  })

  console.log(resultConsonants)
  return resultConsonants
}

consonantsValue(["maria", "florencia", "vazquez"])
//expected output = [13, 26, 28]
//real output = [13, 26, 12]

consonantsValue(["monica", "cecilia", "sepulveda", "gutierrez"])
//expected output = [12, 9, 19, 35]
//real output = [12, 9, 19, 27]
```

Comment: This is indeed correct, but it is the habit on Stack Overflow to treat such mistakes by closing the question with a comment, instead of answering them.